# Space filling algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, space, fill

I'm now working on a problem I can't find a name for, so googling anything is like impossible, therefore I try to describe it here.

Imagine we got a range or some main line on paper. Now we got many smaller lines with randomly variable lengths, plus they have specified at what range they starts. I need to choose a set of these smaller lines, so the spaces together, where we can see the main line, will be lowest possible. So generaly we are trying to cover the main line with smaller chunks that have defined position and length most efficiently.

Other than answer on how to perform this task I'd be glad to know the name of this problem, as I'm sure this is quite common when programming and can be also generalized to more dimensions than one..

As thiton reminded me, ni overlaps are allowed (ofcourse, it would be quite nonsense otherway)

Comment: The specified problem is easy to solve: Choose all lines. Or is overlap forbidden? Or is there any cost in choosing?

Comment: This sounds similar to solving fragmentation.  The difference would be that your lines can't be moved.

Comment: Try looking into the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which sounds related (swap weight for length as your metric)

Comment: @thiton of course, i forgot to write that as I got mind still solving it, but no overlaps are allowed.. going to add that

Comment: I'd be glad that if you downvote, state reason why. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like dynamic programming to me. First of all, sort the intervals so that you can deal with them in non-decreasing order of rightmost point. Now we try and find, for each x, the best way to cover the points <= x. When we pick up a new interval ending at T, we will end up with a cover for points <= T, and the best one comes by looking through the solutions we have so far to find the best solution for points <= S, where S is the largest S <= the left point of our new interval. You can make it reasonably quick to find this best match by storing solutions so far in a sorted collection, like a red/black tree.

Once you have dealt with all of your intervals, you can look through all of the best solutions, accounting for the fact that some of them will end before the end of your line, and pick the overall winner.

Answer (score 4):

It reminds me a little of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem maybe that helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In this problem you have a set of line segments L1...Ln, and some of them overlap. If two line segments Li and Lj overlap, when you can't have both of them in the solution set at the same time; so whenever two line segments would overlap, there's an exclusivity constraint that only one of them can be present in the solution set. Now every line segment has also length, which is the "value" of the line segment, and your problem is equivalent to asking for a set of line segments that has maximal value but where all the exclusivity constraints are obeyed, i.e. there are no overlapping segments in the solution. The fact that the original problem is stated in terms of Euclidean geometry and real numbers doesn't change the fact that the actual problem is combinatorial and of finite nature.

It is not KNAPSACK and it is not SET COVER either. It looks like an instance of weighted SET PACKING ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing)), but whether the problem instances here form an NP-complete problem I don't know, because the geometry of the original problem limits the constrain structures that can be generated. Likely it is, though.

UPDATED

This is per @mcdowella's answer below, it is not NP-complete but an instance of a problem that can be solved efficiently. See the comment below for all links and remarks.

Comment: I am glad to see somebody who mentions NP-completeness and actually has the reducibility relationship the right way round. I suggest that the problem is not NP complete, because if you guess enough to google dynamic programming interval you find http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos423/lectures/06dynamic-programming.pdf which solves it under the name of weighted interval scheduling via memoization in time n lg n (O(n) if pre-sorted).

Comment: @mcdowella Great research :) Thanks :) +1

Answer (score 0):

This problem is nearly equivalent to the *[Set Cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)*, an NP-complete problem.  It differs in that SCP is stated in terms of finite sets.  Your version can be converted to an equivalent weighted SCP problem, and vice versa, in O(K log K) time (K=number of sublines), or to a nearly-equivalent SCP problem without weighting, in O(L/e) time, for L=length of main line and accuracy e.

The wikipedia [SCP article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) mentions three approximation methods: integer linear program formulation, hitting set formulation, and greedy algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

Solution:  choose all the line segments.  You can not do any better, because every point that possibly can be covered will be.